# Efficient way to show that the alternating group $A_3$ is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I understand in order for a group $A$ to be abelian, you must show that for any $2$ elements $x, y \in A$:

$xy = yx.$

However, given that $A_3$ has the set $S_3 = \{(1), (2), (3), (12), (13), (23), (123)\}$, it seems too complicated to prove the abelian property for all $21$ possible pairs of elements ($\binom{7}{2} = 21$).

Comment: $S_3=\{(), (12), (13), (23), (123), (132)\}$, and $A_3$ has only half of those elements.  And there are other ways to show a group is abelian; for example, if you can show that a group is cyclic, then it is abelian

Comment: $(1),(2),(3)$ also commute with everything (they are all the identity).

Comment: $A_3 = \{e, (1\ 2\ 3), (1\ 3\ 2)\}$.  Since $e$ commutes with everything, that's only one pair to check.

Comment: By the way, $S_3$ is not abelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, unlike what you wrote, $S_3=\{(), (12), (13), (23), (123), (132)\}$

-- note that $\lvert S_3 \rvert=3!=6,$ and $(1), (2)$, and $(3)$ are all the same (identity) permutation --

and $A_3=\{(),(123),(132)\}$ is the subgroup of even permutations in $S_3$.

Now the identity permutation $()$ commutes with any permutation,

and $(123)$ commutes with its inverse $(132)$.  Therefore, $A_3$ is abelian.  QED

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a few more facts on your toolbelt, one efficient way to go is...

$|A_3| = \frac{1}{2}3! = 3$, which is prime, so $A_3 \simeq \Bbb{Z}/3{\Bbb{Z}}$, which is cyclic, therefore abelian.

Comment: I don't think you need that many facts on your toolbelt. If you know about $A_n$, you know $|A_n | = \frac{| S_n | }{2} = \frac{n!}{2}$. But then $| A_ 3 | = 3$. It's a simple exercise to show that the only $3$ element group is $\mathbb{Z} / 3\mathbb{Z}$: Suppose $x$ is a non-identity element...

Comment: In other words, if a group has prime cardinality, is it cyclic?

Comment: @AdamLee:  yes, because the order of the subgroup generated by any element must divide the order of the group, so must be $1$ or the prime number